# Форматирование кода React и Vue с помощью Prettier

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, форматирование, prettier

Есть например такой код:

```
<PostItem v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id" :post="post" @remove="removePost"/>
```

Как с помощью Prettier форматировать его в такой?

```
<PostItem 
        v-for="post in posts" 
        :key="post.id" 
        :post="post"
        @remove="removePost"
/>
```

Желательно, чтобы это происходило автоматически.